# Associar dados de usuários de acordo com a url "/profile/username"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

Olá sou iniciante em php e mysql, já rodei tudo quanto é canto  e ainda não consegui entender como associar a minha url amigável ao id. Gostaria de saber como faço para associar e exibir dados de usuários de acordo com a sua url e não usuario logado, preciso que esses dados fiquem públicos.

Eu utilizo wordpress e a base da url é: **/author/usuario/**

Usei uma function wp_rewrite pra deixar assim: **/profile/usuario/**

O código funciona bem porém exibi dados de todos usernames...

```html
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', '', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT user_nicename FROM users WHERE id= '$id' ");
while ($exibir = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    
    // minha consulta
 echo "fullname: {$exibir['user_nicename']} <br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Amigo, uma pergunta. Todos os usuários são autores, certo? Mesmo que não executem função de autor, pois vi que vc mudou a url com rewrite. Mas ao serem adicionado, eles entram no sistema como autor correto? /author/user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá! Sendo seus usuários autores, então você pode pegar o *nickname* pela URL.
Esse código precisa ficar no arquivo PHP, **author.php**. Você encontra o template padrão em:  [codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)

Use `get_the_author_meta()` para recupera os dados solicitados do autor.

```
$usuario = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');
```

Recupere informações do usuário por um determinado campo, assim você terá o ID do usuário. Com o nickname do autor recuperado da URL, então use `get_user_by()`.

Assim, você recupera o ID do usuário. Não do usuário logado, mas sim do autor(nickname) que está na URL

```
$user = get_user_by('slug',$usuario);
print_r($user->ID);
```

Assim, recupera o email:

```
echo $user->user_email;
```

**Outra opção:**

```
<?php
        global $wp_query;
        $curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

        echo "Nome: " . $curauth->first_name . "<br />" .
             "Sobrenome: " . $curauth->last_name;   
/*   
    $curauth->aim;
    $curauth->description;
    $curauth->display_name;
    $curauth->first_name;
    $curauth->ID;
    $curauth->jabber;
    $curauth->last_name;
    $curauth->nickname;
    $curauth->user_email;
    $curauth->user_login;
    $curauth->user_nicename;
    $curauth->user_registered;
    $curauth->user_url;
    $curauth->yim;
*/
```

Comment: Infelizmente não está mostrando os dados acho que montei o código errado.. Mesmo assim muito obrigado você clareou mais meu entendimento!

Comment: Você precisa ir para pág do usuario, siga url:  /author/usuario/

Comment: Todo esse código já está em author.php....

Comment: @Ewerton Editei a resposta. Tente a segunda opção. Compare também seu template com o template padrão em: https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Tente: `global $wp_query;
            $curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        
            echo $curauth->ID;`

Comment: Sim amigo, coloquei e não funcionou. Me desculpe a ignorância mas na consulta com o banco de dados:  <code>SELECT FROM WHERE id = '$' </code> o ID a ser chamado não seria <code>$usuario</code> ?

Comment: @Ewerton Você quer o nome do usuário? Se sim, é só fazer isso: `global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
   
echo "fullname:" . $curauth->first_name;`

Comment: Estranho eu tentei mas não exibiu todos os 2 métodos e esse ultimo sem o banco de dados.. Olha eu quero que essas informações sejam públicas sem necessidade de fazer login, eu já tinha usados curauth pra exibir mas os dados se repetia mesmo que estive-se em outro author, url diferente. Obs. eu utilizei pdo porque ouvir falar que é mais seguro... Esse é meu site: [link](http://www.soundtrackinfo.net)

Comment: @Ewerton Você não precisa desse seu código com chamada `new PDO`. Não é necessário fazer isso para pegar dados no wordpress, ele fornece uma camada para ser utilizada para retornar dados. 
Faça um teste. Pegue o template padrão para o arquivo author.php, é o último código, onde está escrito `Here is a complete sample author.php file, which you can use as an example:` em: https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates Depois utilize a 2ª opção ali na minha resposta(Outra opção:) Use o código que está ali.

Comment: Opa consegui resolver vou editar/add ao post a solução. Obrigado pelas as dicas @Fabiano Monteiro !

Comment: @Ewerton Que bom. Mas como vc resolveu? No caso se foi de uma forma bem diferente da minha explicação, então vc tem q add uma resposta e nao editar sua pergunta. Sua perginta continua a mesma. Nao edite ela e nem acrescente a solução na pergunta. Soluçao do provlema é add como resposta. Agora se foi com minha dica. Vc teria q marca-la como resposta correta a sua pergunta. Entendeu?

Comment: Solução: Aparentemente havia um conflito com a página profile que precisou ser criada por causa do plugin UsersWP. Mesmo alterando o modelo da página "profile" para author.php não recebeu os dados, mas ao desativar o plugin funcionou perfeitamente. Irei agora procurar um meio de usar o plugin porém com essa opção desativada->User Profile Page.